# Maximum size of the iPad Application

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.2

Is any one now the Maximum size of the application when we are playing with it?. I just want to know it because of my application is having more than 10000 images. Please reply me

Thanking you,
Sekhar Bethalam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the maximum size but if you have more than 10000 images it would be better to get them downloaded the first time a user runs the application or even better just download them when the user needs it.

Comment: no problem but can you indicate this as accepted or do you really want to know how much too big :-) your application could be?

Answer (score 0):

The maximum size is about 2GB, but nobody will install an app that large.